# ssh into folder

Tags: ssh

Is there a simple unix command to SSH into a folder? I'd like to make my aliases doing that extra step for me! Feeling dense.

Does this just not exist? `ssh username@mydomain.com:/var/www/mysite`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running:

```
ssh -t username@mydomain.com 'cd /var/www/mysite; $SHELL -il'
```

This will start a batch command with an attached tty.  On the remote side, the batch command will change to the desired directory and start an interactive, login shell (using the shell from /etc/passwd on the remote site).  After that things should work normally.  You might even want to go as far as prepending `env - TERM=$TERM DISPLAY=$DISPLAY`.

Comment: that's a great solution.  even allows for other options, like becoming another user (for example, a role account).

Answer (score 2):

On the servers you connect to, you can add `cd /var/www/mysite` to the `~username/ssh/rc` file .  This would run on all ssh connections but not on normal login sessions.